# this code is getting skipped, does anyone know why?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that will randomly generate a number, then when you guess a number, it either says, 'you won' if you guess correctly, 'higher' if your guess was too low or 'lower' if your guess was too high. Everything is defined just so you know.

I have tried changing the if statements around, and altered the grater than and less than symbols. I have also tryed elif statements for the second two if's.

```
for i in range(50):
  word = input('what number do you think it is?')

  number = randint(0,100000)

  if word > 'number':
    print('the generated number is lower than your guess')
    drawrectanage1()
    penup()
    goto(-180, 0)
    color(colours['bakery'])
    style = ('Roboto', 60, 'bold')
    write('Lower', font=style, align='left')
    hideturtle()

  if word < 'number':
    print('the generated number is higher than your guess')
    drawrectanage1()
    penup()
    goto(-180, 0)
    color(colours['bakery'])
    style = ('Roboto', 60, 'bold')
    write('Higher', font=style, align='left')
    hideturtle()

  if word == 'number':
    drawrectanage1()
    penup()
    goto(-180, 0)
    color(colours['bakery'])
    style = ('Roboto', 60, 'bold')
    write('you won!', font=style, align='left')
    hideturtle()

#there are no error messages and I have tested it and realised that the code...


if word > 'number':
          print('the generated number is lower than your guess')
          drawrectanage1()
          penup()
          goto(-180, 0)
          color(colours['bakery'])
          style = ('Roboto', 60, 'bold')
        write('Lower', font=style, align='left')
          hideturtle()
```

## ... just isn't running and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: `'number'` is a string, not the value you referenced via the identifier `number`. Also `word` is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Now because you have number wrapper in a string your conditional, ie `if` is not checking for the numerical value of number but instead is using string comparison.

In all of the occurrences of conditionals where you are comparing the value of number (which has been evaluated from rand), just unwrap it from string, like

`if word < number`

Comment: I took away the quotation marks form then 'number' value so it looks like you showed:  if word < number (rather than) if word < 'number'. however it hasn't worked. all that has happened is it started to only print lower, rather than higher which it was doing before.

Comment: If would check the other functions that are being called. There is a lot going behind that scenes